# Save and Get a Registry Value in 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software' using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, software-design

In my VB.NET project I want to save and get a registry value in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software" but I am only able to save and get it in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" but not software.

Here is my code:

For setting the value

```
My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.SetValue("Study", "1")
```

For getting the value

```
Dim RegistryCheck As String = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.GetValue("Study")
```

Comment: Try to get the SubKey with [RegistryKey.OpenSubKey("Software", ...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework)) using read/write permissions:  [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck%29%3Bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). If you can get the permission, then create the subkey with `RegistryKey.CreateSubKey`.

Comment: I am only 14 year old and I am not a professional in this, can you explain it a bit.

Comment: You have to verify if you have the permission to write (and also read) from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. If you can't get the required permissions (which is quite possible), opt for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` (`My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser`). Anyway, you have to specify what kind of permissions you're requiring: Read/ReadWrite. See the overloads of the `OpenSubKey()` method. Two of them let's you specify these requirements. If/When you are granted the permission, create the subkey (`CreateSubKey()`) and then set a key value inside it (with `SetValue()`), specifying a value type with `RegistryValueKind`.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, you have helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to verify if you have the permission to write (and also read) from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. If you can't get the required permissions (which is quite possible), opt for HKEY_CURRENT_USER (My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser). Anyway, you have to specify what kind of permissions you're requiring: Read/ReadWrite. See the overloads of the OpenSubKey() method. Two of them let's you specify these requirements. If/When you are granted the permission, create the subkey (CreateSubKey()) and then set a key value inside it (with SetValue()), specifying a value type with RegistryValueKind.